# How can I use "includeJs" function of phantomjs with poltergeist?

Tags: poltergeist

Is there a bridge between native phantomjs functions and the one available with poltergeist ? I would like to use the phantomjs "includeJs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poltergeist doesn't provide any access to PhantomJS' `includeJS`, but its `extensions` feature is implemented via `injectJS` which provides similar functionality, allowing you to specify JS files that get loaded at page creation time, allowing you to polyfill missing features, etc.  http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method . You can specify the files at driver registration time.

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, extensions: ['file1.js', 'file2.js'])
end
```